# subquery inside INSERT statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I just recently found out that subqueries are not allowed in INSERT statements that are inside stored procedures. This is my script:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'truncate table itcustadm.GL_DTPJ_TEST2';   
    insert into GL_DTPJ_TEST2
    (rule_no,
    posted_by_user_id,
    transaction_id,
    transaction_sr_no,
    dr_amount,
    cr_amount,
    tran_crncy_code,
    bkdt_tran_flg,
    bank_desc
    )
    select
    tq.rule_no,
    tq.posted_by_user_id,
    tq.transaction_id,
    tq.transaction_sr_no,
    tq.dr_amount,
    tq.cr_amount,
    tq.tran_crncy_code,
    tq.bkdt_tran_flg,
    (select ent.bank_desc from crmuser.end ent where ent.bank_id = gam.bank_id);
```

But since the **(select ent.bank_desc from crmuser.end ent where ent.bank_id = gam.bank_id)** at the bottom of the SELECT statement is not allowed by Oracle, what's the best way to accomplish this?

I actually have this code right before the INSERT statement, but I don't know how to exactly use it:

```
get_bank_desc := '(select ent.bank_desc from crmuser.end ent ' ||
                'where ent.bank_id = gam.bank_id)';
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are exactly trying for, but below code may be useful for you, you can achieve inserting a SubQuery output into a table using below query sample, but make sure output of the SubQuery is a single row o/p, so that you can escape from `"ORA-01427: single-row SubQuery returns more than one row" ERROR.`

```
insert into test_ins1
values(1,(SELECT COL2 FROM TEST_INS WHERE COL1=1 ));
```

Even then you can use rownum in where condition and take the single value.

Please let me know in case of any doubts

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
     bank_desc_temp bank_desk_type; /* the type defined in crmuser.ent for bank_desc*/

begin

    select ent.bank_desc into bank_desc_temp from crmuser.end ent where ent.bank_id = gam.bank_id;

    execute immediate 'truncate table itcustadm.GL_DTPJ_TEST2';   
    insert into GL_DTPJ_TEST2
    (rule_no,
    posted_by_user_id,
    transaction_id,
    transaction_sr_no,
    dr_amount,
    cr_amount,
    tran_crncy_code,
    bkdt_tran_flg,
    bank_desc
    )
    select
    tq.rule_no,
    tq.posted_by_user_id,
    tq.transaction_id,
    tq.transaction_sr_no,
    tq.dr_amount,
    tq.cr_amount,
    tq.tran_crncy_code,
    tq.bkdt_tran_flg,
    bank_desc_temp;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "not allowed" what do you mean? Did you get an error?

I ask, because subqueries are definitely allowed inside an insert as select statement, providing you have the syntax correct (and the subquery returns at most one row), e.g.:

```
create table test_tab (col1 number, col2 varchar2(10));

begin
  insert into test_tab
  select 1,
         (select 'Yes' from dual d2 where d.dummy = d2.dummy)
  from   dual d;

  commit;
end;
/

select * from test_tab;

      COL1 COL2      
---------- ----------
         1 Yes
```

There are some syntax issues with the code you provided - where is the from clause, and where are the tq and gam aliases defined?

Answer (score 0):

There are two syntax you can use in your insert statement:
(I)

> INSERT INTO table_name( column1, column2....columnN)
>      VALUES ( value1, value2....valueN);

(II)

> INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, ... )
>      SELECT expression1, expression2, ...
>      FROM source_table(s)
>      WHERE conditions;

In your example, you should choose the second approach:

> insert into GL_DTPJ_TEST2 (rule_no,
>                             posted_by_user_id,
>                             transaction_id,
>                             transaction_sr_no,
>                             dr_amount,
>                             cr_amount,
>                             tran_crncy_code,
>                             bkdt_tran_flg,
>                             bank_desc
>                             )
>   select tq.rule_no,
>         tq.posted_by_user_id,
>         tq.transaction_id,
>         tq.transaction_sr_no,
>         tq.dr_amount,
>         tq.cr_amount,
>         tq.tran_crncy_code,
>         tq.bkdt_tran_flg,
>         ent.bank_desc
>   from crmuser.gam
>   join crmuser.end ent
>    on ent.bank_id = gam.bank_id
>   ;

basically, if you want to add records using an insert statement, you should use a full select statement first. Here is how I would do it:
(1)

> select *
>   from table1;

(2)

> select column1
>        ,column2
>        ,column3
>   from table1;

(3)

> select t1.column1
>        ,t1.column2
>        ,t1.column3
>        ,t2.column4
>        ,t2.column5
>   from table1 t1
>   join table2 t2
>    on t2.id = t1.id
>   ;

(4)

> insert into table3 (col1
>                     ,col2
>                     ,col3
>                     ,col4
>                     ,col5)
>   select t1.column1
>        ,t1.column2
>        ,t1.column3
>        ,t2.column4
>        ,t2.column5
>   from table1 t1
>   join table2 t2
>    on t2.id = t1.id
>   ;